# Khan Academy "Analyzing trends in categorical data" help / Self Studying Statistics

Tags: statistics

I am a high school senior looking to self-study statistics in his own time. The reason being that I wish to earn an additional credit for my community college. I own the 3rd edition of "Idiot's Guides to Statistics" (not to be confused with "Statistics for Dummies") and got pretty far into it, about 70 pages in or up to chapter on empirical probability until I realized I needed an additional supplement for statistics. I plan on returning to the book once I finish up what I missed on Khan. The goal is to work around my course curriculum required to test out of the class.

The unit I am investing the most time with is the part on analyzing trends. This unit has either relative or absolute two-way tables and I am having trouble reading (and solving) the relative data distributions. Any help you can provide is much appreciated. For reference: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/analyzing-categorical-data/two-way-tables-for-categorical-data/v/analyzing-trends-categorical-data

Comment: While your personal background is very detailed, the description for the math difficulty you're facing is very vague. My advice is to cut some of the first paragraph (that really doesn't help pin point the problem) and add specific details of what your confusion is.

Comment: My (unsolicited) advice is to get a copy of the textbook used by your local community college in the course you plan to challenge by exam. Perhaps "Idiots" and "Khan" will have occasional useful reference material, but I think your main study should center around a book more closely related to the target class. // For now, perhaps see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144546/interpretation-of-chi-squared-test-for-contingency-table) and other pages on this site dealing with 'chi-squared contingency tables'.

Comment: This site might be useful for getting answers to some of your specific questions on formulas and derivations, and checking to see if you have the right approach on individual problems. Please begin by 'taking the tour' to see how this site works, so you can use the site to best advantage. // Wishing you great success with your study of statistics!